# How to force Angular cli to serve the bundle files from an absolute location rather then base-href

Tags: spring, angular, tomcat, spring-boot, angular-cli

I'm struggling with deploying Angular 4 project built with cli to a Spring boot server.

In the **.angular-cli.json** I added outdir property, which points to a custom folder inside Spring webapp folder, which is accessible directly in the server (webapp/main).

The cli build command I'm using is:

```
ng build --base-href /main/ -a main
```

Which creates the main folder in the webapp, with the index.html containing the following script tags:

```
<base href="/main/">
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
```

which means that these files will be requested with /main prefix, e.g **localhost:8080/main/inline.bundle.js**

Which is fine for a basic app, but becomes an issue when routes are added to the angular app (In Spring, I'm serving the index.html for all paths with /main, to allow the angular routes to work properly, which cause a redirect loop for the bundles, **as they are starting with /main as well**.

**How can I force the generated script tags to use a custom location?** Or at least specifiy the absolute location, and not relay on the base href (so I can change the outDir property to main-app, and problem solved).

The desired solution would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main-app/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

I thought of maybe adding a script that will execute after the ng build which will modify the script tags, but it's a dirty solution, and also won't work with **ng build --watch**, which is crucial for development...

For reference, here is the Spring controller function that maps the /main requests:

```
@RequestMapping("main/**")
public String mainRoute(HttpServletRequest request) {
       return "/main/index.html";
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is `ng build` wiki: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

please use `--deploy-url="/main-app/"` option. this will generate:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main-app/inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main-app/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main-app/scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main-app/styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main-app/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main-app/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just found this option in [one of the closed issues](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4089), tested and i'ts working, thanks!

Comment: Does the --deploy-url value only effect the bundle files list in index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I am running into a similar issue where I used `ng build` and it generates files(index.html, main.js, polufills.js , styles.js etc) in output path(have set this path in angular.json) - resource/static/.  But I can't see any UI when starting tomcat on localhost:8080/ . I believe it's not able to load any of the static files, not sure what I missed or how can we make deployment easier.

I made a controller to serve the front-end part:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "forward:/index.html";
}
```

My index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

But still no user interface when tomcat is running. Even though I used `ng build --deploy-url="/"` it created scripts in index.html as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>
```

Still no luck in getting it to show any UI content on http://localhost:8080/